# Why does my variable resut in an overflow in Java?

Tags: java

Here is my code
`num1` etc are `int` variable

```
double numProduct1;
 numProduct1 = (num1 * num2 * num3 * num4);

System.out.printf("%.3f ", numProduct1);
```

Inputs are respectively (num1,num2,num3,num4):
`100000 200000 300000 500000`

my code would output `-1679818752.000` instead of `3000000000000000000000.000`

Comment: Because 3000000000000000000000 is out of the range for an `int`.

Comment: How Do I fix that? I thought having a double as a variable would work fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You thought that assigning the product to a `double` will allow you to use the whole range of `double`, but that isn't the case. You are only converting the *result* to `double`. The multiplication is still carried out with `int`, and the `int` range applies.

Essentially, this is the multiplication version of [this common question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/int-division-why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0) (well, not exactly :D).

The fix is similar, simply make the first operand `double` (e.g. by casting):

```
numProduct1 = ((double)num1 * num2 * num3 * num4);
```

The expression is now a `double` multiplied by an `int`, and [numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) occurs, promoting the other numbers to `double` as well.